Should we get rid of the [soft-question] and [finance] tags?
I can't imagine any good comes out of these tags. The finance one is so vague on a website about finance that it's like have a programming tag on Stack Overflow. And the soft-question tag just invites career inquiries.

While finance is certainly vague enough (every question should be about finance) to merit deletion, I think there are some appropriate soft-questions, and I've even asked some, so I'd keep that one.

Both finance and soft-question remain extant. In my opinion, the finance tag should definitely be expunged. 
As for the soft-question tag, I agree with @Tal Fishman, that it is appropriate for the site, and should remain. I had a quick look at questions tagged with soft-question. Many are are closed, and occasionally, hilarious.
Should we start a finance tag clean-up, do you think? I think there are less than 30 with that tag on Quant SE.

The finance tag can be deleted by removing all the questions tagged with it. It's my understanding that there is no other way.

@BobJansen is there something special about the finance tag, causing that to be the case? Or is it true about all tags? I made this comment 10 years ago, so I can understand if you don't want to do this now: I just checked and found 636 questions with the finance tag, up from 30 in 2013!!!

I never done this but I believe that the SO term for this is burniation and that it’s a manual process

@BobJansen Ah yes, I am familiar with tag burnination (burination? something like that)! I didn't realize that it was a manual process. In a word, UGH, especially if it requires manual deletion, 636 or more times. I suspect that there are better uses for moderator time than that. Hmmm alternatively... could the tag just be deleted by a Mod? I don't think SO works that way though, as you said earlier. Another approach: Is there any way to prevent new questions from being tagged with finance? That would reduce the scale of the problem without the pain of solving it.
